# Is it possible to use the same RJ-45 connector?

Tags: cables, wire, rj45

Given that the wires are connected to the pins and crimped with a crimp tool; is it possible to "un-crimp" the wires such that they can be unattached from the RJ-45 connector? Whereafter the connector could possibly be used for another cable e.g. CAT-5e cable?

Comment: Just a heads up on your question, RJ45 is a network interface, not a specific cable connection. The CAT-5e cable is a twisted pair cable for RJ45 communications.

Comment: No. You can't reliably 'un-crimp' a CAT-5e connector. Why? They are about $0.04 each. Writing this comment costs more then that. (I don't type that fast!)

Comment: @Oldfart It is not about the price.. just out of curiosity whether it is possible or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in general, it is not possible to "un-crimp" an RJ-xx type connector.

For one thing, there's no way to physically grab the terminals and pull them away from the wire without destroying the plastic housing.

And even if you could, the sharp edges that are required to get a reliable gas-tight connection will have been somewhat blunted by the first usage, and wouldn't be trustworthy in re-use. This is the same reason we never re-used wire-wrap sockets.